# cross-env APP_ENV=production expo r -c throws Invalid project root error after upgrade to Expo 45

Tags: javascript, react-native, npm, expo

After upgrading from Expo v44 to v45, starting my app in production env with the following `npm run start-prod` throws an error `Invalid project root: /Users/user/code/username/projectname/r`.

It seems like it is adding `/r` to my project root for no reason.

I am using a Managed Workflow with Expo.

package.json

```
"main": "node_modules/expo/AppEntry.js",
  "scripts": {
    "start-prod": "cross-env APP_ENV=production expo r -c",
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "expo": "^45.0.0",
    "react-native": "0.68.2",
    "cross-env": "^7.0.3",
...
```